# Access composer libraries from Bluemix PHP Boilerplate

Tags: composer-php, ibm-cloud

When I upload my app to Bluemix, I see it processes my **composer.json** and creates a vendor library in : ***/home/vcap/app/lib***

Given my code resides at : ***/home/vcap/app/htdocs***

How do I code the `<link>` and `<script>` statements in in order to pick up the **CSS** and **JS** files in **/vendor** ?

Comment: What paths have you tried so far? I'm not that familiar with PHP, but would think that something like `../lib/vendor/my.css` would work.

Comment: I've tried a few variations   `<link href="lib/vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">`
 `<link href="/lib/vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">`
 `<link href="../lib/vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">`
 `<link href="../../lib/vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">`
 `<link href="../../../lib/vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Composer is not originally built to manage frontend dependencies like CSS and JS scripts. Additionally, Composer will put all vendor files in a place that should not be accessible from the web, so you cannot access it there. People have built plugins for Composer to allow exposing these frontend dependencies to the internet, or you could use a JS package manager like `npm` to allow putting JS in the right place.